# SMS texting with VB

Tags: vb.net, sms

Program sends SMS text messages from your computer using a G-mail account. This code works fine but it takes a bit of overall time and it is currently sending a text to 4 different email addresses, with only one working. So and ideas or help would be great.

***Help write a loop or something of the sort to simplify my code?***

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try

        Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
        Dim self As New MailAddress("blank@gmail.com")
        Dim Sprint As String
        Dim Verizon As String
        Dim TMobile As String
        Dim ATT As String

        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("blank@gmail.com", "password")
        Smtp_Server.Port = 587
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

        Sprint = "@pm.sprint.com"
        Verizon = "@vtext.com"
        TMobile = "@tmomail.net"
        ATT = "@txt.att.net"


        If txtTo.Text.Length > 1 Then
            e_mail = New MailMessage()
            e_mail.From = self
            e_mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text + Sprint) 'Spint
            e_mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text
            e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
            e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text
            Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)

            e_mail = New MailMessage()
            e_mail.From = self
            e_mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text + ATT) ' AT&T 
            e_mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text
            e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
            e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text
            Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)

            e_mail = New MailMessage()
            e_mail.From = self
            e_mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text + Verizon) ' Verizon
            e_mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text
            e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
            e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text
            Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)

            e_mail = New MailMessage()
            e_mail.From = self
            e_mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text + TMobile) ' T-mobial
            e_mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text
            e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
            e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text
            Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
        End If
        MsgBox("Mail Sent")

    Catch error_t As Exception
        MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to know what an `if` statement is... how about something that checks what the carrier is and then only sends it to the correct carrier. I assume you know what the user's carrier is, right?

Comment: I was planning on sending to the 4 carriers anyways cause I am writing it for a specific function where you wouldn't know the person's carrier.

Comment: [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better place for working code you wish to improve, flagging to move there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't help speed up your sending... But it does reduce your lines of code using the loop you request...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try

        Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
        Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
        Dim self As New MailAddress("blank@gmail.com")
        Dim strCarriers as New List(of String)

        Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("blank@gmail.com", "password")
        Smtp_Server.Port = 587
        Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
        Smtp_Server.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"

        strCarriers.Add("@pm.sprint.com")
        strCarriers.Add("@vtext.com")
        strCarriers.Add("@tmomail.net")
        strCarriers.Add("@txt.att.net")

        If txtTo.Text.Length > 1 Then

            For Each Carrier As String In strCarriers

                e_mail = New MailMessage()
                e_mail.From = self
                e_mail.To.Add(txtTo.Text + Carrier)
                e_mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text
                e_mail.IsBodyHtml = False
                e_mail.Body = txtMessage.Text
                Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)

            Next

        End If

        MsgBox("Mail Sent")

    Catch error_t As Exception
        MsgBox(error_t.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

May I suggest using either Threading or Asynchronous calls to perhaps send multiple emails at the same time maybe?

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what i wanted but just wasn't getting translated to the code while i was writing it so i appreciate it,

Comment: I am actually running into a problem it states the variable strCarrier is use before it is declared. I have tried moving things around a bit to no end yet though.

Comment: Found it 
Dim strCarriers as List(of String) --SHOULD BE--
Dim strCarriers as New List(of String)   and it is golden so thank you for everything!